# How do I call another case in a button click

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, visual-c++

Ok so I've currently been working on a debugger, and I've created a button that is suppose to execute commands in a debugger. But it doesn't do it correctly no matter what I do, here is the code for the two cases.

```
case Execute_Button:
    INPUT_FIELD;
    break;
case INPUT_FIELD:
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_MAXTEXT) {
        char cText[INPUT_CHAR_LIMIT];
        SendMessage((HWND)lParam, WM_GETTEXT, INPUT_CHAR_LIMIT, (LPARAM)cText);

        if (strcmp(cText, "") == 0)
            break;

        SendMessage((HWND)lParam, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"");

        //std::string command = cText;
        HandleCommand(cText);
    }

    break;
}
break;
```

Any help? I honestly do not know what to do.

Comment: Window procedure will receive WM_COMMAND message when a button is clicked. Are you handling those cases there?

Comment: Yes I do I have a handler for the commands in the Main.cpp.

Comment: so if you click that button nothing happens? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes nothing happens I do not know why.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. Edit your question to add more detail, and more code...

Comment: This is how you handle it: switch(LOWORD(wpParam)) // Control identifier
 {
 case IDOK:
  break;

 case IDB_VERIFY_CHECKSUM_BUTTON: break; // Do something here

Comment: @Dai this is not C#

Comment: @Asesh your break statements are wrong

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not provide a way to jump from case to case, with one exception: if you don't have a `break`, `continue`, `return`, or other sort of control flow statement at the end of a case body, it will fall into the next case body (without checking the condition again).

If `ExecuteButton` and `INPUT_FIELD` are next to each other, then

```
case ExecuteButton:
case INPUT_FIELD:
    // shared code
```

Or `ExecuteButton` can have its own code before `INPUT_FIELD`'s.

```
case ExecuteButton:
    // some code
    // fall through
case INPUT_FIELD:
    // shared code
```

The `// fall through` comment is not necessary, but including it makes your code more explicit for others to read.

However, if `ExecuteButton` and `INPUT_FIELD` are not adjacent, you must restructure your code to place the shared code somewhere else (such as a function) where both can access it freely.

---

As for

```
    INPUT_FIELD;
```

The reason why that does nothing but still compiles is because the basic type of statement in C++ is the "expression statement". Remember that assignments and function calls are expressions in C++. Whenever you do assignments or function calls, such as

```
x = y + z;
somethingThatReturns(x, y);
```

you are really evaluating an expression that performs the assignment or function call and results in a value (`y + z` and the return value of the function, respectively) whose value is discarded. So

```
    INPUT_FIELD;
```

will become something like

```
    456; // or whatever the value of INPUT_FIELD is
```

which is then ignored by the compiler without error.